# How to add checkbox column in vue-tables-2?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-tables-2

I have list of users table created in **vue-tables-2**. I want to add checkbox column before each row to select multiple row and before header to select all row like gmail.

can anyone help me out ?

Comment: https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2/issues/298

Comment: @Matanya Thank you

Answer (score 3):

it is very simple.
you should add a column to your vuetables column, just this.
imagine you are defining your tables column in fileds variable.ok ?
i mean something like below,just put this code inside your table coulmn:

```
 fields: [
        {
          name: '__checkbox',  
          titleClass: 'center aligned',
          dataClass: 'center aligned'
        },
        //...
      ]
```

if you wana get more information take look at this link:

https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-tutorial/wiki/lesson-11